# A Review Of, A Review On

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about preposition usage [here](http://www.floridacapitalcases.state.fl.us/Enewsletter/10-mar2.htm):

> "The Florida Supreme Court also conducted **a review on** the proportionality of the death sentence, even though Barnes did not challenge this issue."

Shouldn't it be "*a review* ***of***" instead of "*a review* ***on***"?

Answer (score 2):

*Of* sounds better and is more appropriate, but *on* isn't incorrect.

*On* can mean *concerning* or *regarding* when talking about the subject of a discussion, meeting, or debate.

> You should **consult** your mother **on** what's for dinner.
>
> We'll **debate on** the topic of minimum wage.
>
> They're having a **meeting on** new hire orientation.